# Finding the average rating of each of the movies SQL

Tags: sql, database, stanford-nlp, rating, movie

I'm currently taking the online stanford class on databases, If you could help me solve this sql problem I would greatly appreciate it. Sorry I'm a complete noob.

Table Movie:

```
mID | title | year | director
```

Table Rating

```
rID | mID | stars | ratingDate
```

Table Reviewer

```
rID | name
```

List movie titles and average ratings, from highest-rated to lowest-rated. If two or more movies have the same average rating, list them in alphabetical order.

Comment: This is essentially the same question you just posted an hour ago... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297937/finding-the-average-rating-of-each-movies-sql/14297980#14297980

Comment: If you are taking a class, you should at least show what you attempted.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT distinct m.title, ar.avgRating FROM [Reviewer] rev JOIN [Rating] rate ON rev.rID = rate.rID JOIN [Movie] m ON rate.mID = m.mID JOIN ( SELECT mID FROM [Rating] GROUP BY mID HAVING COUNT(Distinct rID) > 1 ) m2 on m.mID = m2.mID JOIN ( SELECT mID, AVG(stars) as avgRating FROM [Rating] GROUP BY mID ) ar on m.mID = ar.mID ORDER BY avgRating desc