# Hive Query to find out the average rating of movies having rating more than 2

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have a table named `movierating` consisting of the following fields:

```
| ColumnNO. | Name | DataType |

| Column1 | id | int |

| Column2 | movieid | int |

| Column3 | rating | int |

| Column4 | time | string |
```

I have even created the table for the above description using SQL query and loaded it with data successfully. Now I am supposed to write a **Hive** query to find out the average rating of movies having rating more than 2, rounding off the average to two decimal places and save the output in output.txt. In the Bash terminal, I have typed the Hive command as follows (after receiving help from **@SKM**):

```
hive -e "select movieid, round(avg(rating), 2) from movierating group by movieid having avg(rating) > 2;" > output.txt
```

I have even referred [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14298540/finding-the-average-rating-of-each-of-the-movies-sql) for a similar situation, but it didn't help me much.

Please have a look at the screenshots after I ran the query:

[image: Screenshot1]
[image: Screenshot2]

And when I run the command to open the output.txt file as `vim output.txt`, i just get a blank file with no data. I am unable to understand what is being described in the terminal (shown in the screenshot).

Query for table creation:

```
create table if not exists movierating (id int, movieid int, rating int, time string);
load data local inpath '/tmp/Movie-rating.txt' overwrite into table movierating;
```

This is the first step in the challenge which I am attending. Since I am new to hive, I am not much familiar with its working.

Challenge description:

[image: Challenge Description]

where Step1 was to create the table with the above mentioned fields.

Please do help me in this regard.

***Based on Comments***

Output after running the query sent by **@SKM**:
[image: Screenshot4]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your query like below:

```
hive -e "select movieid, round(avg(rating), 2) from movierating group by movieid having avg(rating) > 2;" > output.txt
```

**Snapshot:**
[image]

Comment: Hey @SKM thanks for providing your answer, but when I ran this command, the data did not get copied to the file output.txt, even though it showed **OK** on the screen. Is there anything I need to do?

Comment: Looks like your query has not fetched any record. Please run the query without redirecting the result into the file. If you see output then it will surely write the result into the file.

Comment: I am unable to run the query in the command prompt. All it shows is that same **OK**. Can you show me the query specific to hive as to how I can see the output on the screen?

Comment: Added snapshot !

Comment: I have added the snapshot of the output which I am getting, and also description of the challenge in the question

Comment: All the steps looks correct to me. First run the query `hive -S -e "select movieid, round(avg(rating), 2) from movierating group by movieid having avg(rating) > 2;"` and let me know what output you can see on the console

Comment: Note: `-S` is Slient Mode

Comment: I have run the query which you have sent and added the screenshot of the output in the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223973/discussion-between-mujeebur-rahman-and-skm).

Comment: The problem is solved with data loading using tab delimited format !